# Word 2010: How to change the color of non-printable characters?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, special-characters

I would like to edit my document with non-printing characters (formatting marks: white space, paragraph marks, etc) visible. I find them quite distracting for reading, because they are shown in the same size and color as real text. How I can I change the color with which these special characters are displayed? It is possible to mark a single special character and change its color, but that does not affect the other symbols and new symbols.

I have seen on screenshots that Word for Mac displays the non-printing characters in a light blue, so it seems possible in principle. I would prefer a very light grey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is only possible with Word for Mac.

As Word and Word for Mac are developed individually by different teams at Microsoft it can happen that both versions have a different feature set.